# ¿porqué MediaPlayer no reproduce los audios de manera correcta?

Tags: android, mediaplayer

Estoy trabajando en una galería de fotografías que incluyen un audio de como se pronuncian las cosas que el usuario está viendo en pantalla, lo cual se ejecuta con un botón incluido también en pantalla.

Por cada fotografía tengo la uri de su respectivo audio, y al presionar el botón de reproducir se ejecuta el siguiente código:

```
 View.OnClickListener eventoPlay = (v) → {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btnPlaySound.setClickable(false);

            try{
                Uri myUri = Uri.parse(urlroot + urlAudio); //variables que seteo de manera global al cargar la imagen
                final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), myUri);
                mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                    }
                });

                mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.release();
                        btnPlaySound.setClickable(true);
                    }
                });
                mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                        btnPlaySound.setClickable(true);
                        Log.e("Error in media player", String.valueOf(what));
                        Log.e("Error in media player", String.valueOf(extra));
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                btnPlaySound.setClickable(true);
            }
        }
    };
btnPlaySound.setOnClickListener(eventoPlay);
btnPlaySound.performClick();
```

El código funciona, pero algunas veces el audio se corta antes de terminar de reproducirse, el problema con esto es que no estoy recibiendo ningún `log` de error, he depurado y he notado que `mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener()` nunca se ejecuta (aunque el audio halla sido cortado) y tampoco se ejecuta el bloque de `catch` por lo que no he identificado que está sucediendo.

Estos son los  escenarios que he depurado:

-`setOnPreparedListener()` Se ejecuta de manera natural, siempre (el audio comienza a reproducirse siempre).

-`setOnCompletionListener()` Se ejecuta solamente si el audio se terminó de reproducir (si no se ha cortado el audio).

-`setOnErrorListener()` No se ejecuta nunca, sin importar que el audio se halla cortado.

-`catch` Este bloque tampoco se ejecuta nunca, igualmente sin importar si el audio se corta.

¿alguien sabe a qué se debe esto? ¿hay algo que estoy omitiendo?¿o hay alguna otra forma de depurar que pueda ayudarme a encontrar el origen de la anomalía?

Comment: A que te refieres que no reproduce de manera correcta, ¿se detiene, se pausa, no se escucha? De acuerdo a tu código el url se obtiene de un url, podría ser la red el problema.

Comment: _algunas veces el audio se corta antes de terminar de reproducirse_ ,  Se detiene, sin mas. Mis audios no rebasan los 3 segundos de duración, y ningún archivo de audio supera los 400kb de tamaño en disco. Y no, no es URL de red, es URi hacia el almacenamiento interno del teléfono.

Comment: si reproduces el archivo de audio en alguna aplicación de tu cel, funciona correctamete?

Comment: Así es, se reproduce correctamente, testeado en app de files de google,  google play music y el reporductor integrado en miui de xiaomi.

Comment: revisa mi respuesta y comenta resultados.

Answer (score 1):

Comentas que el audio se encuentra en tu proyecto y no se carga mediante un url, te sugiero en este caso cambiar:

```
mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
```

por

```
mediaPlayer.prepare();
```

me parece que es lo que esta provocando el "bloqueo", no es necesario usar `prepareAsync()` ya que no estas descargando el archivo multimedia.

- `prepare()` es usado para reproducir la multimedia Sincronamente.
- `prepareAsync()` es usado para reproducir la multimedia Asincronamente.

---